# Word comparing and replacing

Tags: php, string, replace, compare

I need some comparing and replacing code in PHP

> Our mission is to empower consumers to
>   Praise Good Service when they receive
>   it and to Report Poor Service wherever
>   they have to endure it.

I need this paragraph to xcompare for some words (for example mission, Good ) and replace that word like this m*****n and G**d

So the result will be like this

> Our m*****n is to empower consumers to
>   Praise G**d Service when they receive
>   it and to Report Poor Service wherever
>   they have to endure it.

How can i do this in PHP?

Please share your ideas and code if any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace(array $from, array $to, $source_string)
```

Comment: $from = array('mission', 'Good');
    $to = array('m*****n', 'G**d');


ps: php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
<?php
$str="Our mission is to empower consumers to Praise Good Service when they receive it and to Report Poor Service wherever they have to endure it.";
$trans = array("mission" => "m***n", "Good" => "G**d");
echo strtr($str, $trans);
?>
```

Comment: what if he want case insensitivity? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This would replace the whole word with stars...

```
$wordlist = "mission|good|praise";
preg_replace("/($wordlist)/ie", 'preg_replace("/./","*","\\1")', $text);
```